# What does Primary Bone / Secondary Bone mean?

Tags: armature, import

[image]

In importFBX panel, what does Primary/Secondary bone axis mean ?

Update : no precise answer yet, but my guess is like this
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue as this, Do you know what they are?

Comment: @tancen Unfortunately no precise answer yet, my only guess is like this (I edited my post)